# Why do tag recommendations and progress show dependent badges?

Tags: feature-request, badges, profile-page

On your profile it shows recommended badges to track, the progress is also shown for some badges (`Civic Duty`, `Copy Editor`, `Electorate`) when you mouse over your review progress

There are several tiered badges, where each badge is doing more of the same

This means you cannot get `badge A` unless you get `badge B` first, so why show recommendations/progress for `badge A`?

So for example if you have edited 15 posts, you have received `Editor`, and are working towards `Strunk & White`.  The review mouse over and the recommended list should not show `Copy Editor` just `Strunk & White`.  If you have zero it should show `Editor`.  Only after obtaining `Strunk & White` should it show `Copy Editor`

Obviously this is not high priority, but if its not that much work, it might be a nice quick hit to improve the site